# How big of a refund can I expect for missing access to gym/pool in an Airbnb?

Tags: airbnb

I’ve rented an Airbnb for a few weeks in a major US city and the listing promised access to an outdoor heated pool as well as a gym. I’ve arrived at the property and was surprised to find out that my key fob isn’t opening the gym/pool area. I’ve messaged the host and they’ve confirmed their unit doesn’t actually have access to said amenities despite the listing saying otherwise.

I’m going to file a dispute with Airbnb soon. What % of the nightly stay price can I expect to be reimbursed? I’ve tried to find reports on the Internet on similar situations but no one provided any numbers.

Comment: I would think that you possibly won't be offered monetary compensation but rather be offered a free nightly credit

Comment: What was the nightly stay price? How much do you think you should be compensated? AirBnB isn’t explicit https://www.airbnb.co.uk/help/article/2868/rebooking-and-refund-policy

Comment: @Traveller $250/night. The building photos featured the gym and the pool as the second and third photos of the listing. Both were listed on the list of amenities as well.

Comment: AirBnB’s FAQs on the topic say only that ‘The size of a refund depends on the severity of the issue, the impact on the guests, whether the guests remain in the space and the portion of the stay affected.’ They give an example of lack of a pool being a major issue. Are there any references to the issue in reviews of the property by previous guests? Are you planning to continue your stay there despite the problem? I’d be asking for at least a 20% refund

Comment: Take screenshots before those disappear.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve ended up settling with the host for 5% of the total cost of the booking, which was satisfactory to me.

Comment: Good, make sure to write a public review. praise the rental (if it was good) and at the same time say that the pool and gym was not accessible; also check that the listing reflects that. (no need to say you had some money back).